# Anodized Aluminum...danger?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I recently got an iMac, but have been feeling anxious about using it as  the keyboard is made of aluminum as is also the actual computer.

the keyboard and computer are made from Anodized aluminum, while the 
base is made from aluminum and plastic,

How long does the anodization last? Like how long does it take for erosion to take place? I read somewhere salts and I think acids could erode it, but I have to check about that. Should I be concerned of amount of aluminum that could be reabsorbed into my skin over several years typing on the keyboard? Granted I could get another keyboard, though I really like the keyboard it came with. In addition, its difficult psychologically  because I guess I worry about just touching the on button to put the computer on..I could also use something else to touch it...but yeah thats just too much trouble over a computer.

The fears stem from a possible but apparently not proven link of alzheimers to increased aluminum in the body.

Considering this is not the same as dietary intake, I would hope that it should not be an issue, and also because its anodized aluminum, nevertheless I am seeking looking for assurance as the internet can be quite brutal and adamant about the position it takes. You know there are these other "health" sites supporting claims that it could cause Alzheimers.

I literally when to look for publications concerning aluminum alzheimers link. But it was not helpful..some of what I saw just perhaps scared me. Granted I did not literally read the whole article mainly just the Abstract. Nor did I commit my self to a period of time to look over the matter.

Anyway, yeah I have to make a decision soon to keep or return the iMac like less than two weeks perhaps; the anxiety is painful. If anyone could give me insight
concerning aluminum and anodized aluminum, if they can be transferred dermally and if so, how much is absorbed and if is significant. I read here that just a small amount is transferred dermally.
http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=1076&tid=34

In addition now to think of it the aluminum could be transferred to the mouth if you were to eat with it without washing hands.yeah not the kind of way I'd want to live worrying about this.

I think soda cans have aluminum s in the soda, but a computer is something I may use nearly everyday, for perhaps hours so..

Comment: It isn't a problem. You're in more danger driving back to the store than you are from the keyboard.

Comment: You might wish to try at [skeptics.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it just is.

Comment: ok thanks orthrocresol..and thanks MaxW for responding...perhaps people who are in the chemist field may know something about anodization..and how long it may take to wear off..nevertheless it does stray off into other areas and the question I guess doesn't totally  fit in this category .so if you want the question closed then

Comment: You are aware that a lot of cookware is made from aluminium or anodised aluminium? So your food will often be in contact with it and in a harsh environment. Also the link between aluminium and alzheimer's  is now thought to be spurious: an artefact of the analytical technique used and not a real link to the disease.

Answer (score 3):

> […] How long does the anodization last? Like how long does it take for erosion to take place? […]

This depends on the thickness of the oxide layer, the cleanliness of the aluminium surface before anodization, the curvature (deposition might be different at edges), the mechanical and the chemical stress. In summary, the question might be, at least, very difficult to answer.

But since you're more worrying about possible health issues rather than about the quality or look of the computer, you might take the following into consideration:

1. A lot of antacids still do contain large amounts of aluminium salts, such as magnesium aluminium silicates. These product are used orally! To my knowledge, higher frequencies for Alzheimer disease among patients that frequently use these antacids has never been observed.
2. The German *Alzheimer Gesellschaft* does not see a correlation between aluminium and Alzheimer disease, see [this note in German](https://www.deutsche-alzheimer.de/unser-service/archiv-alzheimer-info/leichtes-metall-mit-schweren-folgen-aluminium-und-die-alzheimer-krankheit.html).
3. In a more recent report, the *Bundesinstitut für Risikobewertung (BFR)*,  a German federal institution for risk assessment has addressed the question in a [FAQ](http://www.bfr.bund.de/en/faqs_about_aluminium_in_food_and_products_intended_for_consumers-191148.html) (in english). Let me cite a paragraph:

> **Is there a connection between aluminium intake and Alzheimer’s disease?**
> Various studies have tried to demonstrate a connection between aluminium intake and Alzheimer’s disease. However, due to the patchy data situation, they do not provide irrefutable scientific evidence for such a connection.

In summary, I agree with the comment given by *MaxW*. Don't worry about about intoxication from touching the keyboard, but pay attention when you cross the road.